spacy-llm & SpanCat for address parsing
I'm currently developing a project to standardize and correct a dataset of inconsistently formatted addresses using spaCy-LLM and spaCy.SpanCat.v3. The goal is to train a model on examples of correctly labeled addresses so it can automatically normalize and categorize each component of an address into predefined labels: ["NAME", "STREET", "BUILDING", "LOCALITY", "SUBAREA", "AREA", "CITY"].
The dataset includes addresses in incorrect order/format and various other anomalies. An example of the raw data is: Building 8c lane No 1 mart building phase 6 bara bukhari DHA
The expected output for this row would be:
Name: Building 8c
Street: lane No 1
Building: mart building
Locality: bara bukhari
Subarea: phase 6
Area: DHA
City: Karachi
My end objective is for the model to process an input(input.txt) where the model will parse and correctly label each part of the address. I am seeking insights or advice from anyone who has used spacy-llm for similar tasks, especially for parsing addresses and formatting tasks. Additionally, I'm interested in incorporating LangChain/Ollama models into this workflow but am not planning to use Prodigy.
Any guidance or tips on setting up this system effectively would be greatly appreciated!
I set up a spaCy configuration to use a large language model (LLM) for address parsing. My config defined the model, task, and label details, and I provided example data in a JSON file.
    [nlp]
    lang = "en"
    pipeline = ["llm"]

    [components]

    [components.llm]
    factory = "llm"

    [components.llm.model]
    @llm_models = "spacy.Dolly.v1"
    name = "dolly-v2-3b"

    [components.llm.task]
    @llm_tasks = "my_namespace.AddressParsing.v1"
    labels = ["NAME", "STREET", "BUILDING", "LOCALITY", "SUBAREA", "AREA", "CITY"]
    description = The main delivery_address column contains all the labels,
                This column has to be standardized.

    my_other_config_val = 0.3

    [components.llm.task.label_definitions]
    NAME = "The exact address (plot number) of place itself."
    STREET = "The name or number of the street."
    BUILDING = "The name of the building."
    LOCALITY = "The locality or neighborhood."
    SUBAREA = "A subdivision of the area."
    AREA = "A larger division of the locality."
    CITY = "The name of the city."

    [components.llm.task.examples]
    @misc = "spacy.FewShotReader.v1"
    path = "examples.json"

I expect the system to standardize and label address data correctly based on this setup but how do i train the model. Im stuck with that part of the implementation. helppp!
